# Reindex data from Elasticsearch 1.X to ElastichSearch with old _timeStamp to new Field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to migrate my data from an old Elasticsearch(Version 1.4.4) Cluster to a new one (5.1)

I am using the [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote) api in the new Elasticsearch, but can't get the old `_timestamp` to a new field `timestamp`. Everything else works fine.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://oldhost:9200"
    },
    "index": "source",
    "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  }
}
```

Are there any way to add a script tag to set the new field `timestamp` from the old `_timestamp`?

Comment: Did you manage to make this work? I tried a lot of things

Comment: No , sorry , had other timestamp fields in the data i could use

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain this will work, but using the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) you can specify a tiny bit of script that might be able to read the old `_timestamp` field (although I've never tried it personally):

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://oldhost:9200"
    },
    "index": "source"
    "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.timestamp = ctx._timestamp"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, wern't at work today, will try it first time tomorrow. i think however i have tried something like this, is ctx the new object or the old one from the remote source?

Comment: Dosn't work, the timestamp field ends up  "timestamp": null, :/

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, see this other question and my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379396/elasticsearch-1-x-add-field-copy-of-timestamp the idea is to first copy the `_timestamp` field in your 1.4 index as a regular field and then this problem won't exist anymore.