# Elasticsearch 1.x add field copy of timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, timestamp

I am working in ES 1.5.2. I have an index with documents, with stored timestamp values. I want to add a regular field to it, which will assume the value of the _timestamp field for that document. How can I do this? I could do

```
PUT twitter/_mapping/new_timestamp
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "float"
    }
  }
}
```

to create a regular field, but how can I copy over all the _timestamp values to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 1.5.2, you can use the [update by query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) in order to reindex your documents and copy the `_timestamp` field to a regular field.

After installing the plugin with the following command:

```
bin/plugin -url http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/yakaz/elasticsearch/plugins/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/1.0.0/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery-1.0.0.zip install elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery
```

And making sure that [dynamic scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file, you'll be able to run the following command

```
POST /twitter/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.new_timestamp = ctx._timestamp”
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know that this plugin exist for 1.5

Comment: Ahh, I realize why this was not working. The timestamp was enabled, but not stored. Have created another post for this.

Comment: Shall we close this post too?